# JavaScript and CSS

Tags: css, ajax

I am wanting to implement Thickbox, which I have done a number of times.

My issue is that I am doing some jQuery like:

```
$('#txtData').load('aerialProductListing.inc');
```

and when this happens, the CSS is lost.

How can I get the stylesheet recognized again? or can i do something inline to work around?

Edit: txtData is simple:

```
<div id='txtData'><p></p></div>
```

aerialproductListing.inc is simple HTML and PHP, nothing fancy and to long to post, but the Thickbox piece isL

```
<a href="tip.inc?height=400&width=600" class="thickbox small" title="<b>US Tips">US Tip Chart</a>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML surrounding txtData as well as the contents of aerialProductListing.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the CSS is lost"? Style may easily be lost, but a CSS defined style should apply always.

Comment: @annakata - the CSS simply doesn't work, but If I move the link I want to click to outside the javascript call it works. So something happens when I put the link inside the .inc I mention and call it from javascript as I posted

Answer (score 1):

If a `<style type="text/css"></style>` element is declared *inside* the `#txtData` element, it will be gone after `$('#txtData').load(...)`.

Comment: @orip - but it isn't and I understand it would be wiped out. The style sheet is defined on index.php and on index.php I do an include to a file hat displays a chunk of the site and in the piece I include I do some javascript stuff when the user clicks on the link and the last line is the $('#txtData').load(...). to finish the process. It is when the user clicks the link I mentioned that the style sheet stuff does not work any more